# Blazor with ChartJs.Blazor: Unhandled Exception Could not find 'chartJsBlazor.onClick'

Tags: blazor, chart.js, blazor-server-side

I am working on a Blazor Server application where I am trying to implement a pie chart using the ChartJs.Blazor library. However, I am facing an issue when rendering the component. The error I receive is:

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'chartJsBlazor.onClick' ('chartJsBlazor' was undefined).
```

The error seems to originate from blazor.server.js.
It's specifically mentioning an issue with chartJsBlazor.onClick.

I have added the necessary script references in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="_content/ChartJs.Blazor.Fork/ChartJsBlazorInterop.js"></script>
```

My Chart.razor component is set up as follows:

```
@using Frontend.Data
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
@using ChartJs.Blazor.PieChart
@using ChartJs.Blazor.Common
@inject AppDbContext DbContext

<Chart  Config="_config"></Chart>



@code {

    private List<string> ColorList = new List<string> { "#007599", "#A7261B", "#69942F", "#5864AD", "#B33389" };

    [Parameter] public List<DonutChartData>? Data { get; set; }


    private PieConfig _config;
   

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _config = new PieConfig
        {
            Options = new PieOptions
            {
                Responsive = true,
                Title = new OptionsTitle
                {
                    Display = true,
                    Text = "Subscription Overview"
                }
            }
        };

        foreach (var data in Data ?? new List<DonutChartData>())
        {
            _config.Data.Labels.Add(data.Label);
        }

        var colors = Data?.Select(d => GetColorForLabel(d.Label)).ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<string>();
        var values = Data?.Select(d => (int)d.Value).ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<int>();

        PieDataset<int> dataset = new PieDataset<int>(values)
        {
            BackgroundColor = colors
        };


        _config.Data.Datasets.Add(dataset);

        
    }
    

    int ColorIndex = 0;
    private string GetColorForLabel(string? label)
    {
        if (label == null) return ColorList[0]; 
        var color = ColorList[ColorIndex % ColorList.Count];
        ColorIndex++;
        return color;
    }

    
}
```

What might be causing the Could not find 'chartJsBlazor.onClick' error?

Are there any additional steps or configurations I need to do to properly set up ChartJs.Blazor in a Blazor Server application?